# Opening MODIS Raster MOD13Q1 .hdf file comes in as Float32 instead of 16-bit signed integer

Tags: qgis, modis, hdf

Trying to open a MODIS 16 day composite NDVI raster from the .hdf file.  After selecting just the NDVI band, QGIS nicely displays the image.  However, on this image the range of values is between -3.57096e+06 to 7.97734e+07.  So outside the expected range of -3000 (fill value) and 10000.  Looking at the Metadata, says the Data Type is Float32 instead of the expected 16-bit signed integer (Int16?).

Is there a way to choose the Data Type of the raster being imported or to change it once imported?